# Can I use my ADF Filter activity to copy two or more file types?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a location where there are `.csv, .txt and .hr` files altogether.
I am using a filter in my ADF pipeline to filter `.txt` right now and copying it using Filter Settings condition `@contains(item().name, '.txt')`.
[image]
Now, I want to copy .csv files as well.

I have tried Filter condition as `@endswith(item().name, ['.txt','.csv'])` and `@contains(item().name, ['.txt','.csv'])` which doesn't work.

So,
What other options I can use And If I can use my existing Filter to copy both csv and txt files How do I do that ?

Comment: you can use the expression `@or(contains(item().name, '.txt'),contains(item().name, '.csv'))` to filter both csv and txt files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  `or`  function with the  `contains`  function to filter both  `.txt`  and  `.csv`  files in your Azure Data Factory pipeline. Below is the expression:

```
@or(contains(item().name, '.txt'), contains(item().name, '.csv'))
```

In this condition, the  `contains`  function is used to check if the file name contains either  `.txt`  or  `.csv`. The  `or`  function is used to combine the two comparisons using the logical OR operator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. 
But one question- When both file type goes through copy can we modify the destination folder path to two folder path in copy configuration? eg. txt goes to ../txt folder and csv to ../csv path

Comment: You can give the expression like `@split(item().name,'.')[1]` in folder path. This will make sure to copy the file dynamically to txt or csv folder